# Why are c++ Header Guards names in capital and with underscore?

Tags: c++, guard, capitalize

I noticed that .h files have their name capitalized and uses underscore for header guards....why is that?

for example take "doThat.h"

the header guard would be:

```
#ifndef DO_THAT_H
#define DO_THAT_H
```

why is it capitalized and underscored like that? even if in the main.cpp you only type `#include "doThat.h"` to use the file?? There is some real programing reason to this? why not just type :

```
#ifndef doThat.h
#define doThat.h
```

Comment: A better question is, why not just type `#pragma once`. It is de-facto standard

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessor definitions have to use valid identifiers. Dots are not valid in identifiers.

There is also a convention that preprocessor definitions (especially preprocessor macros) use all-uppercase names, to distinguish them from non-preprocessor identifiers. (It's not a hard-and-fast rule, though; for example, `errno` is usually a macro, but it's not uppercase.)

Comment: This is especially helpful on terminals that do not highlight syntax. Having the preprocessor instructions in uppercase makes them easy to tell apart.

Comment: What would be an example of a non-preprocessor identifier? sorry i'm a noob :(

Comment: @user3624683 Preprocessor identifiers are ones that are processed by the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) program, usually known as `cpp`; generally, that's anything created using `#define` (or via the `-D` option to your compiler), though there are some builtin preprocessor identifiers like `__cplusplus`. Any identifiers that aren't processed by the preprocessor are, by definition, non-preprocessor identifiers. Most variable and function names are non-preprocessor identifiers.

Comment: FYI, `errno` is an odd case. Very likely _way_ back in the days before POSIX threads, `errno` was an ordinary variable. But then threads came along and the committee needed `errno` to be thread-local _and_ not break existing code, so they came up with a macro hack that accomplished both.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a naming convention, not a hard rule.  It is not uncommon to see `DOTHAT_H` or `DOTHATH` or `DoThatH` instead, for instance.  What is important is that the `#define` use a unique identifier that does not clash with other files. *Some* variation of the calling filename is typically used.